# How to concatenate digits from words with dynamic lengths in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, count, sum

I have a column A with comma separated words. In subsequent columns, I replace the words with IDs using Vlookup. I am intending to fill in data with an output that looks like this `a:4:{i:0;s:2:"41";i:1;s:2:"40";i:2;s:2:"43";i:3;s:3:"153";}`

I need to concatenate the first number with `i:0;s:2:` Where `0` is the first index of the numbers and `2` is the number of characters in the first number. The second number `40` becomes i:1;s:2: while the third `143` becomes i:2;s:3: Take note of `3` because `143` has `3` characters.

```
41 40 143
```

I have made strides but making it dynamic is where I am having the challenge. So that the formula is dynamic when the text in A changes.

My formulae
in D2 `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="","",(LEN(A2:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,",",""))+1)))` This counts the number of words in A.
in E2 using `flatten, trim, split, textjoin` I replace the words with IDs.

In K to N Columns I have the individual numbers and P to S columns I have the number character count.

The expected output is in F2. But the formula is unfinished and probably there is a much easier way to do it. My formula is not dynamic meaning it still needs fixing to work with the other words dynamically without changing the formula time and again.

Link to spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12rXI4e8pYSdTHlIVgkKl66KNYUqQv3z9luazIxKADQM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,"a:"&LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "[^,]", ))+1&":{"&
 SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR("i:"&SEQUENCE(1, 100, )&";s:"&
 LEN(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(A2:A, ","), B2:C, 2, 0))&":"""&
     VLOOKUP(SPLIT(A2:A, ","), B2:C, 2, 0)&""";")),,9^9))), "; ", ";")&"}"))
```

[image]